# Cannot manually load kears imbd dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

following this instruction: [the alternative to from keras.datasets import mnist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690203/the-alternative-to-from-keras-datasets-import-mnist/51632839)

I am able to load the mnist dataset, with the following lines:

```
f = gzip.open('C:/.../Datasets/mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
if sys.version_info < (3,):
    data = pickle.load(f)
else:
    data = pickle.load(f, encoding='bytes')
f.close()

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = data
```

But when I try the same for the IMDB dataset, which i saved as tar.gz file, which the following command:

```
imdb = gzip.open('C:/.../Datasets/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz', 'rb')
if sys.version_info < (3,):
    data = pickle.load(imdb)
else:
    data = pickle.load(imdb, encoding='bytes')
imdb.close()
```

I get the error:

```
UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow
```

I am not allowed to load it with:

```
imdb = keras.datasets.imdb

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)
```

because I am behind a proxy.

Comment: Why are you trying to load the IMDB dataset manually?

Comment: cause I am behind a proxy...and not allowed to load it directly...

Comment: There are alternatives in that case, we have an XY problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are behind a proxy, there are alternatives to download the dataset:

- Download the file at https://s3.amazonaws.com/text-datasets/imdb.npz
- Put the downloaded file inside `C:\Users\<your_username>\.keras\datasets`
- Use `keras.datasets.imdb.load_data()` normally.

If you get errors about pickle, then look at: [How to fix 'Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False' for imdb.load_data() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890813/how-to-fix-object-arrays-cannot-be-loaded-when-allow-pickle-false-for-imdb-loa)

Comment: when i Run: `imdb = keras.datasets.imdb.load_data()`, I receive the error: `ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False`

Comment: @PV8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890813/how-to-fix-object-arrays-cannot-be-loaded-when-allow-pickle-false-for-imdb-loa

Answer (score 0):

It works well behind the proxy:

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = 
imdb.load_data(path = "/Users/username/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/keras/datasets/imdb.npz", num_words=10000)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).